# SQL Table with Date

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, sqldatatypes

So I am creating an SQL table:

```
create table Customer 
(customerID char(25) not null,
name char(50),
address char(25),
dateRegistered DATETIME(6),
noOfDvdHiring int(5),
primary key (customerID));
```

I receive the following error:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I believe that this has something to do with DATETIME, is this the correct way to display a date? (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` doesn't sound like MySQL. You sure it's MySQL?

Comment: Might just be Oracle SQL

Comment: This is an oracle error message. MySQL is incapable of generating an ORA-nnnnn message.

Comment: If everything else fails, read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF30020 the valid data types are actually documented

Answer (score 2):

**`MySQL 5.6`** - works ok

```
create table Customer 
(customerID char(25) not null,
name char(50),
address char(25),
dateRegistered DATETIME(6),
noOfDvdHiring int(5),
primary key (customerID));
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5be56/1/0)**</kbd>

**`MySQL 5.5`** - use without `DATETIME(6)`:

```
create table Customer 
(customerID char(25) not null,
name char(50),
address char(25),
dateRegistered DATETIME,
noOfDvdHiring int(5),
primary key (customerID));
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/78c18f/1/0)**</kbd>

**`Oracle`**:

```
create table Customer 
(customerID char(25) not null,
name char(50),
address char(25),
dateRegistered DATE,
noOfDvdHiring int,
primary key (customerID));
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo3`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b7d23/1/0)**</kbd>

Keep in mind that `MySQL` and `Oracle` are different products and they support different datatypes and may use own syntax.

Answer (score 0):

> (customerID char(25)

You should use **VARCHAR2** instead. **CHAR** is right padded to the size defined. It is wastage of storage space.

> dateRegistered DATETIME(6)

`DATETIME` is not a supported **data type** in Oracle.  You could use:

- **DATE**
- **TIMESTAMP**

DATE can store upto seconds precision. To go beyond, use TIMESTAMP which is an extension of the date data type.